# Split Single Column(1,000 rows) into two smaller columns(500 each)

Tags: python, pandas, csv

#### How to split a single column containing 1000 rows into chunk of two columns containing 500 rows per column in pandas.

I have a csv file that contains a single column and I need to split this into multiple columns. Below is the format in csv.

**Steps I took:**
I had multiple csv files containing one column with 364 rows. I concatenated them after converting them into a dataframe, but it copies the file in a *linear* fashion.

**Code I tried**

```py
monthly_list = []
for file in ['D0_monthly.csv','c1_monthly.csv','c2_monthly.csv','c2i_monthly.csv','c3i_monthly.csv','c4i_monthly.csv','D1_monthly.csv','D2i_monthly.csv','D3i_monthly.csv','D4i_monthly.csv',
                        'D2j_monthly.csv','D3j_monthly.csv','D4j_monthly.csv','c2j_monthly.csv','c3j_monthly.csv','c4j_monthly.csv']:
    monthly_file = pd.read_csv(file,header=None,index_col=None,skiprows=[0])
    monthly_list.append(monthly_file)
monthly_all_file = pd.concat(monthly_list)
```

**How the data is:**

| column1 |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| . |
| . |
| 364 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| . |
| . |
| 364 |

***I need to split the above column in the format shown below.***
**What the data should be:**

| column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 5 |
| . | . |
| . | . |
| . | . |
| 364 | 364 |

Comment: Use join instead on concat

Comment: Try use `axis`: `pd.concat(monthly_list, axis=1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer updated to work for arbitrary number of columns**

You could start with number of columns or row length.  For a given initial column length you could calculate one given the other. In this answer I use desired target column length - `tgt_row_len`.

```
nb_groups = 4
tgt_row_len = 5

df = pd.DataFrame({'column1': np.arange(1,tgt_row_len*nb_groups+1)})
print(df)

    column1
0         1
1         2
2         3
3         4
4         5
5         6
6         7
...    
17       18
18       19
19       20
```

**Create groups in the index for the following grouping operation**

```
df.index = df.reset_index(drop=True).index // tgt_row_len

   column1
0        1
0        2
0        3
0        4
0        5
1        6
1        7
...
3       17
3       18
3       19
3       20

dfn = (
    df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x['column1'].reset_index(drop=True)).T
        .rename(columns = lambda x: 'col' + str(x+1)).rename_axis(None)
)

print(dfn)

   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     1     6    11    16
1     2     7    12    17
2     3     8    13    18
3     4     9    14    19
4     5    10    15    20
```

**Previous answer that handles creating two columns**

This answer just shows 10 target rows as an example. That can easily be changed to 364 or 500.

**A dataframe where column1 contains 2 sets of 10 rows**

```
tgt_row_len = 10

df = pd.DataFrame({'column1': np.tile(np.arange(1,tgt_row_len+1),2)})
print(df)

    column1
0         1
1         2
2         3
3         4
4         5
5         6
6         7
7         8
8         9
9        10
10        1
11        2
12        3
13        4
14        5
15        6
16        7
17        8
18        9
19       10
```

**Move the bottom set of rows to column2**

```
df.assign(column2=df['column1'].shift(-tgt_row_len)).iloc[:tgt_row_len].astype(int)

   column1  column2
0        1        1
1        2        2
2        3        3
3        4        4
4        5        5
5        6        6
6        7        7
7        8        8
8        9        9
9       10       10
```

Comment: What if I need to split into 300 column?

Comment: @NitinKumar I updated my answer to work for arbitrary number of columns

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if anyone has a more efficient solution but using pd. merge on a temp column should solve your issue. Here is a quick implementation of what you could write.

```
csv1['temp'] = 1
csv2['temp'] = 1
new_df=pd.merge(csv1,csv2,on=["temp"])
new_df.drop("temp",axis=1)
```

I hope this helps!